# A Twist on the Birthday Problem

Tags: probability

I was asked the following question: given a debate team with 27 members, what is the probability that at least three members have a birthday on the same month?
   Since this is an at least question, it is easier to find the complement.

$P(x\geq3) = 1 - (P(0) + P(1)+P(2))$

$P(0) = (\frac{11}{12})^{27} $
   $P(1) = 0$ 
   $P(2) = 1 \cdot(\frac{1}{12})\cdot(\frac{11}{12})^{25} $

Therefore, $P(x\geq3) = 0.895.$
But is this the right approach?

Comment: Hint:  there are twelve months, so if $≤2$ are born in each month the maximum number of debaters is...

Comment: @lulu I don't quite follow. The maximum number remaining? 3? Or the maximum you could have and still only have 2 or less per month? 24?

Comment: If at most two are born in each month then there can't be more than $24$ people.  As you have $27$, the probability you want is $1$.

Comment: @lulu Feeling pretty dumb right now...

Comment: Don't.  Easy sort of thing to miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a pigeonhole principle question not a probability question.

Imagine that no month has three or more birthdays in it. There are 12 months so there could only be 24 debaters. As you have 27 debaters then at least one month must have at least 3 people in it. So the probability is 1.